# Jenkins exec sshCommand within withCredentials block but FAILURE

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, ssh-agent

I follow the guid from Jenkins [official site](https://www.jenkins.io/zh/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/), and write the pipeline here:

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = "dev-server"
remote.user = "root"
remote.host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" // xxx will replace as my host server 
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
remote.logLevel = 'FINEST'
pipeline {
  // node docker env
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Preparation') {
      steps {
        // git branch
        git branch: 'stage', credentialsId: 'SSH_OF_XXX_BY_XXX', url: 'git@gitee.com:xxx/xxx.git'
        sh 'rm -rf package-lock.json'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      { docker 'node:lts-alpine' }
      steps {
        sh 'node -v'
        sh 'npm -v'
        sh 'npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org'
        sh 'npm install'
        sh 'npm run build:stage'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
     environment { 
       key = ''
     }
     steps {
        echo 'Deploying'
        // package as tar.gz
        sh 'tar -C dist -czvf jenkins-yunqidi.tar.gz ./'
        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'SSH_OF_XXX_BY_XXXX', keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
            // some block
            echo '1213123 ${key}'
            sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'echo pwd'
        }
        // sshagent (credentials: ['SSH_OF_XXX_BY_XXX_RSA']) {
        // script {
        //         sshCommand remote: remote, command: "pwd"
        //     }
        // }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I exec sshCommand within both withCredentials and sshagent, all FAIL. Error msg is following

#### withCredentials & sshagent

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session$connect$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy:85)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$_connectInternal_closure1.doCall(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility.retry(Utility.groovy:52)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.util.Utility$retry.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy:83)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connectInternal(ConnectionManager.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager.connect(ConnectionManager.groovy:59)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.connection.ConnectionManager$connect.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.wetRun(SessionTask.groovy:61)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.SessionTask.call(SessionTask.groovy:48)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service.run(Service.groovy:81)
    at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.SSHService.executeCommand(SSHService.groovy:177)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution$CommandCallable.execute(CommandStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.call(SSHMasterToSlaveCallable.java:32)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any friend meet the same situation, and suggest some advice.

Or is there any other pipeline guide site?

Comment: Can you check if there is sah connection between Jenkins server to remote host. You will be able to successfully login to remote server using Jenkins user if there is ssh connection. Please check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invoked ssh command within credential blocks but you have not assigned that credentials to remote object. You need to assign the private key identity into remote object like below, this will resolve your authentication error.

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'SSH_OF_XXX_BY_XXXX', keyFileVariable: 'key')]) {
            // some block
            echo '1213123 ${key}'
            remote.identityFile = key
            sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'echo pwd'
        }
```

Thanks,
Kiruba